# Changes in Parent Luma theme is not reflected in Child Luma theme in Magento 2.3.0?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, luma-theme, parent-child-theme

I have created seven child themes and one parent theme for these seven child themes.
All seven child themes points to their parent theme, we've named ***"Master"***.

```
<theme>
    <title>Child Theme 1</title>
    <parent>Company/Child1</parent>
</theme>
<theme>
    <title>Child Theme 2</title>
    <parent>Company/Child2</parent>
</theme>
<theme>
    <title>Child Theme 3</title>
    <parent>Company/Child3</parent>
</theme>
```

...and so on...

The ***"Master"*** parent theme points to ***"Magento/Luma"***.

```
<theme>
    <title>Master</title>
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
</theme>
```

Theme locations:

```
app/design/frontend/Company/Master
app/design/frontend/Company/Child1
app/design/frontend/Company/Child2
app/design/frontend/Company/Child3
```

**Now to the problem**

In the Parent theme ***"Master"*** layout file:
*app/design/frontend/Company/Master/Magento_Catalog/layout/theme.xml*

I have added:

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="catalogsearch.product.addto.compare" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="category.product.addto.compare" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="crosssell.product.addto.compare" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="related.product.addto.compare" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="upsell.product.addto.compare" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true" />
```

But nothing happens in the seven child themes?
Changes does not reflect.

**Some questions:**

1. ***app/design/frontend/Magento*** is empty, no luma theme, nor blank for the parent theme ***"Master"*** - is this correct?
2. The parent theme "Master" is pointing to ***"Magento/Luma***" - should it be ***"Magento/Blank"*** instead?

Greatly appreciated if someone can help me shed some light on this,
Thanks,

Comment: Maybe I should just copy

`/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma`
to
`app/design/frontend/Company/Luma`?

Comment: Or maybe both the blank and luma theme?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make some change in the child theme "theme.xml".

You are code is

```
<theme>
    <title>Child Theme 1</title>
    <parent>Company/Child1</parent>
</theme>
<theme>
    <title>Child Theme 2</title>
    <parent>Company/Child2</parent>
</theme>
<theme>
    <title>Child Theme 3</title>
    <parent>Company/Child3</parent>
</theme>
```

You need to changed into

```
<theme>
    <title>Child Theme 1</title>
    <parent>Company/Master</parent>
</theme>
<theme>
    <title>Child Theme 2</title>
    <parent>Company/Master</parent>
</theme>
<theme>
    <title>Child Theme 3</title>
    <parent>Company/Master</parent>
</theme>
```

Hope this will help you.
Thanks